# Insert missing features by comparing multiple fields

Tags: arcpy, list

I have two separate layers, I need to update one layer if the features are not in the other layer. I was thinking of using two fields to compare both features and if missing use insert, to insert it.
Below is what I have.

```
import arcpy

#set workspace to folder of shapefiles or geodatabase
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\GIS_Data\Projects\water.gdb" 

fc1 = r"C:\Temp\GIS_Data\Projects\water.gdb\bmits" 
targetFC = r"C:\Temp\GIS_Data\Projects\water.gdb\Cas2"

dsc = arcpy.Describe(targetFC)
fields = dsc.fields
out_fields = [dsc.OIDFieldName, 'GlobalID','OBJECTID_1']
fieldnames = [field.name if field.name != 'Shape' else 'SHAPE@' for field in fields if field.name not in out_fields]

manhole_listA = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, ["WellID", "Par"] + fieldnames) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        manhole_listA.append([row[0], row[1]])

icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(targetFC,["WellID", "Par"]+ fieldnames)

manhole_list = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(targetFC, ["WellID", "Par"] +fieldnames) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        manhole_list.append([row[0], row[1]])
        print(manhole_list)
        if manhole_listA in manhole_list:
            continue
        icur.insertRow(row)


##for row in icur:
##    checkVale = row[0], row[1]
##    if checkVale in  manhole_listA:
##        continue
##    icur.insertRow(row)
##
```

I made changes to my code  I am getting printed messages, but for some reason the insertCursor is not adding the missing features.

manhole_listA length:  505
manhole_list length:  272

```
#set workspace to folder of shapefiles or geodatabase
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\GIS_Data\Projects\water.gdb" 

fc1 = r"C:\Temp\GIS_Data\Projects\water.gdb\bmits" 
targetFC = r"C:\Temp\GIS_Data\Projects\water.gdb\Cas2"

dsc = arcpy.Describe(targetFC)
fields = dsc.fields
out_fields = [dsc.OIDFieldName, 'GlobalID','OBJECTID_1']
fieldnames = [field.name if field.name != 'Shape' else 'SHAPE@' for field in fields if field.name not in out_fields]

manhole_listA = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, ["WellID", "Par"] + fieldnames) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        manhole_listA.append([row[0], row[1]])
print("manhole_listA length: ", len(manhole_listA))

icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(targetFC,["WellID", "Par"]+ fieldnames)

manhole_list = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(targetFC, ["WellID", "Par"] +fieldnames) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        manhole_list.append([row[0], row[1]])
        print(manhole_list)
        if manhole_listA in manhole_list:
            continue
        icur.insertRow(row)
print("manhole_list length: ", len(manhole_list))
```

Comment: may be this `["WellID", "Par" +fieldnames]` should be `["WellID", "Par" ] +fieldnames`?

Comment: I made a change to something similar to what you suggested but still no go.         ```field = ["WellID", "Par"]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, field + fieldnames) as cursor:```

Comment: I added a print statement and it prints that all records are not in the list. Which I know it snot correct.   ```with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(targetFC, field +fieldnames) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        manhole_list.append([row[0], row[1]])
        print(manhole_list)
        if manhole_list in manhole_listA:
            print("PermitNum {0}".format(row[0]) + "Not in manhole_list")```

Comment: I thinks its your use of `field +fieldnames`. That is not standard syntax. You need to provide a simple list of field names within the cursor. Concatenating lists with strings makes no sense to me and frankly poor coding style. Look at the help file on cursors see how its done correctly and by everyone else on the planet.

Comment: Also shoving code into the comments is bad especially for python as indentation is everything, your code is almost unreadable. If your are suggesting possible alternatives edit your question and insert there. No one has the time or effort deciphering your code  shoved into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is already mentioned in the comments, but for clarity or anyone new to Python. Python actually can treat a string as a list, so you can index places within a string just as you would in a list.

`"ParcelNum1"` is the same as the list `["P","a","r","c","e","l","N","u","m","1"]`.

When you combine a string and a list using the + symbol, you would end up with:

`"ParcelNum1"+ fieldnames`  is the same as `["P","a","r","c","e","l","N","u","m","1","FieldName1","FieldName2"]`

Or as you had `["WellID", "Par" +fieldnames]` you end up with nested lists `["PermitNum",["P","a","r","c","e","l","N","u","m","1","FieldName1","FieldName2"]]`

Instead you would want to bracket the strings:
`["ParcelNum1"] + fieldnames` results in `["ParcelNum1","FieldName1","FieldName2"]`

Or `["PermitNum","ParcelNum1"] + fieldnames` would result in `["PermitNum","ParcelNum1","FieldName1","FieldName2"]`